# Setar virgula em um retorno Json

Tags: c#

Galera estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em C# com API. Ele vai consulta e mostra o resultado. Coisa bem simples.
Mas em um dos meus meus métodos ele retorna a altura do cara sem virgula. Vem por exemplo assim: 175.

Alguém pode me ajudar a colocar uma virgula ali no meio ? 
Sou bem leigo na linguagem C#

Valeu

```
var json = JObject.Parse(result);

            pessoa.altura = (string)json["height"];
```

Comment: Resumindo: ele te dá o resultado em centímetros e você deseja em metros?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Resumiu bem. kkk

Comment: Isso depende de como você tá armazenando. Se você armazena centímetros, ele vai retornar centímetros. Daí é só aplicar uma conversão para metros, mas antes é bom ter plena ciência do domínio dos seus dados

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado eu guardo tudo em string, É um app pequeno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá.
Utilize o pacote [**newtonsoft json**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/).
Ele permite você trabalhar com maior facilidade a conversão de jsons para objetos .net e vice-versa.

[Aqui](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) você pode aprender mais como utilizar esta biblioteca.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Mas o problema não é trabalhar com o JSON, mas sim formatar uma string do tipo "175" em "1,75". Essa biblioteca faz isso? Se sim, seria legal adicionar o trecho de código para isso na sua resposta.

Comment: Como mencionei ela faz o parse de valores de maneira bem simplificada, tratando objetos, strings, floats, ints, decimals e afins. Se vocês clicarem no link **aqui** que irá redirecionar para a página mantenedora do projeto, já na home tem um código mostrando o quão fluente é o uso da ferramenta. Mas para facilitar vou editar a resposta com um trecho de código.